# Error: No se puede modificar datos al realizar actualización

Tags: java, mysql, jframe

Mi problema es que a la hora de querer editar la información me salta el mensaje de que no se pudo modificar y no me edita nada. Aquí el codigo:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
Connection conectar = null;

try{

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     conectar = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/proyecto", "root", "");


 }  catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 try{
 String sql= "UPDATE datos SET Nombre=?,"+ "Apellido=?,"+ "Email=?,"+"Foto=?,"+"Ruta=?,"+"Posicion=?,"+"Compañia=?,"+"Nota=?,"+"Telefono=?" +"WHERE Nombre='"+jTextField1.getText()+"'";

 PreparedStatement pst= conectar.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
        pst.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
        pst.setString(5, jTextField5.getText());
        pst.setString(6, jTextField6.getText());
        pst.setString(7, jTextField8.getText());
        FileInputStream ArchivosFoto;
        FileInputStream Archivofoto = new FileInputStream(jTextField7.getText());
        pst.setBinaryStream(8, Archivofoto);
        pst.setString(9, jTextField7.getText());
        int n = pst.executeUpdate();
        if (n > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se modificaron los datos de manera correcta :D");
            tablaDatos();

        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error, no se pudo modificar los datos :c");

        }
 }  catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Te sale algún error ? porque según veo la columna foto es el número 4 y lo estás seteando en la columna 8, quería agregar que el orden de inserción o actualización deben de ser igual a la de tu base de datos.

Comment: Hola Manuel, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general y así ganar tu primera medalla). Sería ideal que editases la pregunta para añadir algo más de información: qué es lo que estás intentando hacer con el código compartido y qué error concreto te sale (y dónde). Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.